# How do I differentiate between an audio URL and a video URL?

Tags: iphone, video, mime-types, avaudioplayer

I have some URLs to play content from, but I have to identify whether the given URL contains video or audio. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to tell what kind of content a URL references is to send a HEAD request and check the Content-Type returned. Or you could just start retrieving the resource and decide what to do with it when you get the headers. That's the approach web browsers take.

Comment: url consists mp3 wxtension at the end